# How to make equivalency in Python?

Tags: python, csv

Hard problem for me, i have a csv with 2 columns

```
4,8
5,64
6,12
7,54
8,2
```

... and more than 50 entries

and a second CSV with one column (the second column entries from the first csv).

I try to find (and write) the corresponding entries from my first csv:

```
54,7
8,4
12,6
8,4
64,5
54,7
...
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by "equivalence"? Can you give an example with a "solved" CSV? (i.e. what should be instead of the "?" in that last example?)

Comment: What do you mean by "equivalence"? Can you explain what you mean, or some example also would be useful.

Comment: Are you trying to transpose the columns?  If you are, it'd help to convey your point clearer by maintaining the ordering between both your expected and actual results.

Comment: @Makoto it's exactly what im looking for; i'm not maintaining the order in my example cause i can't change the order or reorganize my columns in my CSV files.

Comment: Load the contents of A. Use each line as a dictionary, where B is the key and A is the value. Apply this to the data in B.

Comment: I can't be more specific if I don't know exactly how the CSV files look like. I.e. if they have column titles, if that series of `----` is in the file or not, and if there are other columns beyond these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... if you have two csv files and the second has one column of B values:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    line_values = [line.strip().split(',') for line in f.readlines()]
transposed_values = dict([(v.strip(), k) for k, v in line_values])
with open('test2.csv') as fi:
    with open('out.csv', 'w') as fo:
        for line in fi.readlines():
            B = line.strip()
            try:
                print >>fo, '{}, {}'.format(B, transposed_values[B])
            except KeyError:
                print >>fo, '{}, ?'.format(B)
```

Input file, `test.csv`:

```
4, 8
5, 64
6, 12
7, 54
8, 2
```

Input file, `test2.csv`:

```
54
8
12
8
64
54
```

Output file, `out.csv`:

```
54, 7
8, 4
12, 6
8, 4
64, 5
54, 7
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by order. Do you have a second file with one column (the B entries from the first file) and you want to find the corresponding A entries?

Comment: Yes @xnx, my second file have just one column (B entries from first file but in different order), and i try to find the corresponding A entries

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you get the `A` column for the CSV file you want to write, but let's assume the values, in order, are somehow in a list `As`.  Then:

```
import csv

d = {}
with open('toread.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for a, b in r:
        d[b] = a

with open('towrite.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for a in As:
        w.writerow(a, d[a])
```

Comment: This won't work if there are duplicate `b` values with different `a`'s.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't seem compatible with the problem as expressed by the OP.

Comment: Same problem, order is different between my first and second CSV

Comment: @Marco, no idea what you mean by "same problem" (same as **what**?!) -- **have** you, or have you not, tried exactly the code above (with appropriate names for the files) plus a setting to `As` as you desire (e.g `54, 8, 12, 8, 64, 54` based on your Q as it appears in this very moment)?